# Convert string to NSURL with character '\\' inside

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I coding with **Swift 2.0**.

I got my URL string like this:

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:\\1.txt"
```

When I convert it into NSURL, it returns nil.

```
let OrginUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: try this: let urlString = "http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:\\\\1.txt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues that need to be addressed:

In order to include a `\` it must be escaped because it is itself the escape character.

'\' characters are not allowed in URLs so they need to be URL encoded

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:\\\\1.txt"  
print("urlString: \(urlString)")  

var escapedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())  
print("escapedString!: \(escapedString!)")  

let orginUrl = NSURL(string: escapedString!)  
print("orginUrl: \(orginUrl!)")
```

> urlString:
>   [http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:\\1.txt](http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:%5C%5C1.txt)
>
> escapedString!:
>   http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Fgetfile%2F%3Ffilepath=C%3A%5C%5C1.txt
>
> orginUrl:
>   http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Fgetfile%2F%3Ffilepath=C%3A%5C%5C1.txt

Answer (score 2):

You should use unicode instead of backslash twice.

> `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated: Use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(_:)` instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL components or subcomponents since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.
>
> Documentation [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000157-SW12)

Below is the example code:

```
let myLink = "http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C:\u{005C}\u{005C}1.txt"
var newLink = ""
if let queryIndex = myLink.characters.indexOf("?"){
    newLink += myLink.substringToIndex(queryIndex.successor())
    if let filePathIndex = myLink.characters.indexOf("=")?.successor() {
        newLink += myLink.substringWithRange(queryIndex.successor()...filePathIndex.predecessor())
        let filePath =  myLink.substringFromIndex(filePathIndex)
        if let pathEscaped = filePath.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()) {
            newLink += pathEscaped
        }
    }
}
if let newURL = NSURL(string: newLink) {
    print(newURL, separator: "", terminator: "")
} else {
    print("invalid")
}
```

And result you will get:

> "http://example.com/api/getfile/?filepath=C%3A%5C%5C1.txt"